# Filter out both copies of duplicated files in a vector with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm processing files in a directory to convert a `.raw` filte to `.wav`. The output goes in the same folder and I need a way to generate a list of raw files that don't have a corresponding wav.

e.g convert this

```
files  <- c('2019-09-30_16:29.raw', '2019-09-30_16:29.raw.wav', '2019-10-06_09:13.raw', '2019-10-06_09:13.raw.wav', 
'2019-10-06_09:15.raw', '2019-10-06_09:15.raw.wav', '2019-10-11_06:18.raw', '2019-10-11_06:18.raw.wav', 
'2019-10-11_08:55.raw', '2019-10-11_17:42.raw', '2019-10-12_05:53.raw', '2019-10-12_07:34.raw',
'2019-10-12_08:43.raw')
```

to this

```
unpaired_files <- c('2019-10-11_08:55.raw', '2019-10-11_17:42.raw', '2019-10-12_05:53.raw', '2019-10-12_07:34.raw', '2019-10-12_08:43.raw')
```

If I strip the file extensions, `duplicated` or `unique` will get rid of the duplicates, but keep one copy of each pair. I want to get rid of both copies to just leave the unpaired files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty straight forward solution using the `%in%` function

```
files  <- c('2019-09-30_16:29.raw', '2019-09-30_16:29.raw.wav', '2019-10-06_09:13.raw', '2019-10-06_09:13.raw.wav', 
            '2019-10-06_09:15.raw', '2019-10-06_09:15.raw.wav', '2019-10-11_06:18.raw', '2019-10-11_06:18.raw.wav', 
            '2019-10-11_08:55.raw', '2019-10-11_17:42.raw', '2019-10-12_05:53.raw', '2019-10-12_07:34.raw',
            '2019-10-12_08:43.raw')


#Strip of the extension
basename<-gsub("\\..+", "", files)

#find duplicated base names
dups<-unique(basename[duplicated(basename)])

#find files which are not on the duplications list
files[!(basename %in% dups)]

#[1] "2019-10-11_08:55.raw" "2019-10-11_17:42.raw" "2019-10-12_05:53.raw" "2019-10-12_07:34.raw" "2019-10-12_08:43.raw"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to "convert" the `"wav"`s to raws, which yields set `"g1"`. Then identify the `"raw"`s in a second step and make set `"g2"`. Finally what you want is the `setdiff`.

```
g1 <- paste0(unique(gsub("(.*?)\\..*", "\\1", files[grep("wav", files)])), ".raw")
g2 <- files[grep("raw$", files)]
setdiff(g2, g1)
# [1] "2019-10-11_08:55.raw" "2019-10-11_17:42.raw" "2019-10-12_05:53.raw"
# [4] "2019-10-12_07:34.raw" "2019-10-12_08:43.raw"
```

All in one:

```
setdiff(files[grep("raw$", files)], 
        paste0(unique(gsub("(.*?)\\..*", "\\1", files[grep("wav", files)])), ".raw"))
# [1] "2019-10-11_08:55.raw" "2019-10-11_17:42.raw" "2019-10-12_05:53.raw"
# [4] "2019-10-12_07:34.raw" "2019-10-12_08:43.raw"
```